# Extracting password protected files in a if loop in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ksh, 7zip

I am using 7za command to unzip password protected files.
Lets consider a scenario, I have one file who's password is a combination of mmyy.
dates(mmyy) can be for current month, previous month or previous to previous month.
eg 1213 or 1113 or 1013 (mmyy:format)
below is a sample code snippet i wrote

```
      function currmonth
     {
       curr_mon=`echo $(date +%x)`
       cyy=`echo $curr_mon| awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}'`
       cmm=`echo $curr_mon| awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
           curr_pswd=`echo ${yy}${mm}`

     }
     function prevmonth 
     {
        prev_mon=`echo $(date +%x -d 'last month')`
        yy=`echo $prev_mon| awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}'`
        mm=`echo $prev_mon| awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
        prev_pass=${yy}${mm}
     }
     function prev2month 
     {
        prev2_mon=`echo $(date +%x -d '2 month ago')`
        p2pyy=`echo $prev2_mon| awk '{print substr($0,9,2)}'`
        p2pmm=`echo $prev2_mon| awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'`
        prev2mon_pass=${p2pyy}${p2pmm}

     }
     function IA_oper
     {

           files=`ls abc*.zip`
            for eachfile in $files; do
```

## Not sure after this, here am not sure how do I loop them using If condition

```
        if [expression];then
      7za x -p$curr_pass $eachfile 


        elif [expression]; then
              7za x -p$prev_pass $eachfile 


       elif [expression]; then
      7za x -p$prev2mon_pass $eachfile 

       else
          mailx -s" cannot be extracted" abc@xyz.com
       fi
     done   
     }
```

I want to execute them in if loop if all the conditions fail it mails me with an error 
I am not sure how to do it please assist me with this

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing as an "if loop".

Comment: i am just trying a way in which i can loop the three possibilities together and see which one works if none i return an error mail

Comment: I don't think you understand what you are doing and I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @RobinGreen: i have one file which has a variable password,password is a combination of dates(mmyy), dates(mmyy) can be this month or previous month or 2 months back. i need to check which month works, for the same reason i tried looping them so i can determine which one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try them all, your "condition" needs to check for success or failure, which is reported via the exit status of a command.  In bash, you find this with the variable `$?`

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success!"
fi
```

In your case, you want to stop trying new passwords once you find one that works, so use the keyword `continue` to jump back to the next iteration of the loop.

```
for eachfile in $files; do

    # Try each password, and move on as soon as we find one that works
    7za x -p$curr_pass $eachfile
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        continue;
    fi

    7za x -p$prev_pass $eachfile
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        continue;
    fi

    7za x -p$prev2mon_pass $eachfile
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        continue;
    fi

    # Fallthrough.  We get here only if all of the above failed.
    mailx -s" cannot be extracted" abc@xyz.com
done
```

By the way, you can save a bunch of awk parsing by allowing `date` to format your passwords for you.  Just tell it you want MMYY:

```
date +%m%y -d '2 month ago'
```

Comment: what if i want to rename the file for the password which works so in the each if block can i add an else which will help me to rename the file if the password works?

Comment: If a password works, the continue inside the `if` clause is hit, which will take execution back to the next "eachfile" in the `for` loop.  So if you want to do something additional on success, put it before the `continue`.  As this script gets more complex, consider putting your possible passwords in an array so you can loop through them and remove the 3x duplicate code.

Comment: I got it Thanks Peter. yes you are right an array would make it more efficient.